# Execution of CL.EXE by VS 6.0 C++ results in "There is no disk in the drive.. <corrupt drive name>

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cl.exe

Execution of CL.EXE by VS 6.0 C++ results in "There is no disk in the drive. Please insert a disk into drive xxxx" where XXX is a series of junk characters. This implies some corrupt registry var or env var, but I cannot find. I have tried a complete de-install / re-install of VS 6.0 to no avail.

P.S. I have been using VS 6.0 for years with no issues. My VS 2008 install is fine but I also need my VS 6.0

Answer (score 1):

During install, for some reason these entries reference the install disk instead of your hard drive.

Tools - Options - Directories - in the Drop Down box select Library Files
remove these two entries. There should be an entry to C:\Program Files\DevStudio\VC\LIB and \MFC\lib instead

D:\DevStudio\VC\LIB
D:\DevStudio\VC\MFC\lib

Answer (score 0):

If you create a fresh Win32 Console Application in C++ 6.0 does the same problem happen?  If not that would suggest your problem might be specific to your project rather than applying to C++ 6.0 overall.  In which case you might just open your dsw or dsp file with notepad and look for the odd drive name.

If you go to Tools | Options | Build tab and make sure the "Write Build Log (.plg)" box is checked then Visual Studio will log everything it does to a file named .plg.  That file can be opened with notepad (or your favourite text editor).  You should be able to see the command line passed to CL.EXE - something like this...

> Creating command line "cl.exe
>   @C:\DOCUME~1\XPMUser\LOCALS~1\Temp\RSP2EF.tmp"

Just before that you should see the contents of the response file...

> Creating temporary file
>   "C:\DOCUME~1\XPMUser\LOCALS~1\Temp\RSP2EF.tmp"
>   with contents [ /nologo /MLd /W3 /Gm
>   /GX /ZI /Od /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D
>   "_CONSOLE" /D "_MBCS"
>   /Fp"Debug/STOFLO1.pch" /Yu"stdafx.h"
>   /Fo"Debug/" /Fd"Debug/" /FD /GZ  /c 
>   "C:\TestPrograms\VC++\STOFLO1\STOFLO1.cpp"
>   ]

That might help you figure out where your odd drive name is being used which in turn might tell you where it is coming from.

If that doesn't help, you might want to use a tool like Process Monitor from [SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals).  Run Process Monitor while you bring up VC++ 6.0 and build your project then use Find to search the monitor output for the odd drive name.  There's a good chance that PM will capture whatever access retrived that name (from the registry or wherever).  If it does, that again may give you a clue as to what needs to be changed.

Comment: Brilliant!  Indeed a new console project worked. I had not tried this as I went to try a couple of other known "working" projects which also failed. Whne this failed I had to use task manager to close CL.EXE. It seems magically a non-existant drive letter "K:" inserted itself into my settings, replacing "..". K: is an SD card, never involved with compilation. Many thanks, I was rather thrashing around with random tricks to solev this. I never thought my project settings were vulnerable to being corrupted!